# What is the correct way of shorten this nat based multiple ports?

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, tcp

Can these rules shorten to single line:

```
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3050 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3050
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3051 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3051
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3052 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3052
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3053 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3053
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3054 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3054
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3055 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3055
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3056 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3056
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 3050:3056 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3

post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 3050:3056,5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3
```

Comment: Thank. How about adding an other port like 5000. 3050:3056,5000 ?